# apache redirect permanent not working with #

Tags: apache, character-encoding, ascii, http-redirect

inside an apache location I've a redirect permanent directive that works fine.
If I add a # character at the end of the url to redirect the redirect doesn't work.

for example this works fine:

```
 Redirect permanent /primoacc/sigma/app/index https://example.com/primoacc/sigma/app/index#/home
```

this doesn't work:

```
Redirect permanent /primoacc/sigma/app/index# https://example.com/primoacc/sigma/app/index#/home
```

I believe is something related to # character. I have try to substitute # with %23 but with no result.

any idea?

thanks

Comment: That's the "comment" character in a httpd.conf file - I've never seen it used in the middle of a line, but odds are high that everything from there on to the line's end are ignored

Comment: yes you are right, I've also try to insert the two url in "" but with no result.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not related to to # character, redirect rule needs to be coded something like this...

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/primoacc/sigma/app/index$ https://example.com/primoacc/sigma/app/index#/home
```

Redirect rules are case sensitive, you should not be using a redirect rule for what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for reply, using your example it works but if I call https://example.com/primoacc/sigma/app/index#/home I enter in loop. is there a way to redirect only the exact url with the hash character at the end?

Comment: Ok, could you explain me which rule should I use? I've to redirect an exact url to another, so I believe that the redirect rule was appropriate. thanks ;)

Comment: You should be using rewrite rules as these can be configured not to be case sensitive

Comment: sorry, why are you speaking about case sensitive? I've an exact url that will never change